# how to rotate reflection from Imageview?

Tags: reflection, javafx, rotation, imageview

My question concerns  rotating the reflection of imageview. Is it possible or not?
my code is shown below:

```
    Group root = new Group();
    File file = new File("c://Users/Garm/Downloads/AnimGif.gif");
    Image image1 = new Image(file.toURI().toString()); 
    ImageView view = new ImageView(image1);
    view.setFitHeight(image1.getHeight()/2);
    view.setFitWidth(image1.getWidth()/2);
    root.getChildren().add(view);
    view.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    Reflection reflection = new Reflection();
    reflection.setFraction(1.0);
    reflection.setTopOffset(55.5);
    reflection.setTopOpacity(0.600);
    reflection.setBottomOpacity(0.001); 
    view.setEffect(reflection);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
    stage.setTitle("Animated GIF");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.show();
```

In my code, I would like to object reflection was rotated 90 degrees. Whether it is feasible, and if not, can anyone give an idea to solve this problem. Thank you for all your help and guidance on this topic.

Comment: What does "rotate the reflection" mean?  Can you edit the question to provide an image that demonstrates this?  Or, if you don't have enough reputation to do that, upload a demonstration image to [imgur](http://imgur.com) and link to it from your question.

Comment: @jewelsea I think he wants the ImageView to be normal (angled 0) and the reflection to be angled at 90 degrees. In short, the reflection would be of the ImageView which has been rotated by 90 degrees, but the ImageView should remain unrotated.

Comment: @jewelsea this is what I meant. I solved this problem by not using the reflection effect. I used the second ImageView and i used  the rotate method. Sorry for my english.